# Why does Google Chrome is opening my React App instead of the API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I have a link in my react app supposed to open in an another page a pdf but google chrome is opening the react application instead of my api that renders the pdf
The url of my pdf is `/api/file/:_id` and my react app is at `/`
Express routes below :

```
app.use("/api/file", fileRouter)
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/front/build/index.html"))
})
```

When I click on my link

```
<a href={`/api/file/${invoice._id}`} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">link</a>
```

chrome is opening the react page and not my file whereas Safari open my file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In react you should use `<Link>` component from `react-router-dom`. 
[react-router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6)

If you want to redirect to outside website, you have to do something like: 
 `<Link to={{pathname: "//www.stackoverflow.com/"}} target="_blank">StackOverflow</Link>`

Comment: That don't solve the problem. Both could be use with a target _blank, React Router just pass the data to a <a></a> markup

Comment: So try to paste whole link to 'href' attribute, with 'localhost:port' included. It's the difference, becuase you using relative (to react-app) path

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I've used a <a></a> markup with the href attribute so the problem isn't here, my code works well in Safari and Firefox, I want to understand why Chrome has this behaviour to solve my problem